# How to get maximum value per rows by top-level groups in multilevel Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Multilevel DF in Pandas:

```
A     B
a  b  a  b
----------             
1  2  3  4
2  3  3  2
7  2  1  0
```

Now I would like to get maximum values in each row per level-0 groups like this:

```
A  B
----
2  4
3  3
7  1
```

What is the proper query? `df.groupby(level=0).apply(max)` works only row-wise, not column wise.

Comment: Don't use `apply(max)`, use Pandas' `.max()` as in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `axis` keyword argument in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in combination with `level=0`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 3, 2],
        [7, 2, 1, 0]
    ],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["a", "b"]])
)

out = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
```

out:

```
   A  B
0  2  4
1  3  3
2  7  1
```